HTML table header is not repeat on each while printing
When I set HTML table header height 200px (I think, this depends on browser, you can replicate this by keep increasing the height value), it's not repeated on every page while printing it. Same behavior is observed on Chrome and Edge.
Table header content is dynamic and some times it occupies half of the page, and requirement is to repeat it on every page while printing.


<table style="border: 1px solid black;">
  <thead style="font-size:22px !important; vertical-align: top; text-align:left; height:200px;">
    <tr>
      <th style="background-color: lightyellow;">
        Header Text
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody style="font-size:8px !important;">
    <tr style="background-color: lightblue;">
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: lightblue;">
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: lightblue;">
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: lightblue;">
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: lightblue;">
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: lightblue;">
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: lightblue;">
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: lightblue;">
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: lightblue;">
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: lightblue;">
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: lightblue;">
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: lightblue;">
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: lightblue;">
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: lightblue;">
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: lightblue;">
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: lightblue;">
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: lightblue;">
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: lightblue;">
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: lightblue;">
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: lightblue;">
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: lightblue;">
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: lightblue;">
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: lightblue;">
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: lightblue;">
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Body text
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



The header should be repeated on every page while printing.

Couldn't reproduce this with the exact 200px header height, needed a bit more in my test, but I suppose that could depend on specifics such as paper size, etc. Looks to me as if these browsers disable repeating headers, if they take more than a certain percentage(?) of the print page height - which probably is a sensible thing to do in most situations. Not sure if there is anything you can do about this.

I used your code snippet, added more <tr> to have multiple pages when printing and tried the print option on google chrome version 126.0.6478.127, the header is repeating when viewing the print preview.

@atish.s please try with increasing header height also.

@atish.s work fine on portrait orientation but not on Landscape orientation . (Firefox last version).  look's like a browser  bugg...
